# Cordova and windows 10 universal app (winjs) restarts instead of resume on tile click

Tags: cordova, win-universal-app, windows-10, winjs

When tapping the tile for a running app it re-starts the app instead of resuming. Actually, it resumes the app, but after a split second it re-loads the whole thing and you land on the start page. For my app which is a GPS tracker, hitting the tile results in the same as crashing the app.

On WP8 we could add ActivationPolicy="Resume" to DefaultTask in the manifest file and the app would resume on tile click.

Anyone knows how to make this work on Cordova Windows 10 UAP?

I am on Cordova version 4.2.0 for windows and its a WinJS project.

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32600539/windows-10-cordova-app-restart-instead-resume)

Comment: Have you ever resolved this? would you mind to share a solution in case you've got it up and running correctly. thank you

Comment: See below. This was solved in 4.3.1. However, in the meantime I migrated my code to win 10 UWP javascript app which worked well for me.

Comment: I have cordova 5.3.3 and experience the problem...

Comment: The Cordova tools version is not the same as the platform version. The latest platform version for windows is 4.3.1. Cordova tools is now at 6.0.

Comment: Same issue. My cordova version is '3.7.0'. Is there any other way rather than updating cordova version?

Comment: cordova-windows@4.4.2 and I see the same problem :(

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed since cordova-windows@4.3.1: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10446